# how can I continously run a unix script in background without using crontab.

Tags: linux, unix, solaris

how can I continously run a script in background without using crontab. The script should run even after I logout and is acceptable if it doesen't start after system reboot.I am new to unix.

Answer (score 4):

There's a couple of ways of doing this but the neatest way is to use [screen](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/grp/cd/soft/epics/extensions/iocConsole/screen.1.html).  This lets you create a session which lives perminently on the machine and you can simply reconnect to to check on the progress of your long running process.

If you don't wish to use `screen` you can use `nohup` this allows you to run a task like:

`nohup mytask &`

Your task will now run in the background and will survive a log off, however there's no way to take control of it again, unlike with `screen`.

Comment: I have a small script that I need to check certain condition continously and as soon as that condition is met the program should execute. Can this be done. I thought of using crontab where script runs every 5 min but now I want that to be done without crontab.

Answer (score 2):

```
if [ "x$1" != "x--" ]; then
$0 -- 1> /dev/null 2> /dev/null &
exit 0
fi
```

This is how you can run a script as a **daemon**. First your script (the father) will create a copy of himself (a child) so it is considerd as a process of the father. Then the father kills itself while the child is still running. Guess what happens when you do such a thing ? The child is attached to the init process. So even if you logout, the script will still run.
You can even start it without the "&" operator because you start the father which is killed a millisecond after.
You can take control over it again like any program running on your computer.

By the way it's not a real "daemon" program, it's just kind of emulation. You can't just start it at the boot (I mean really the BOOT and not the loggin) if you want to start it as you login, quite simple put it in your `.xinitrc`

The main advantage of this solution is that your script doesn't depend on any other programm such as "nohup" which is really bad I think.

Regards
PS : If you want some informations about what the command above does, just ask me. It's just a "parameter" thing.

Comment: hey can you please let me know how this works.actually I have a small script that I need to check certain condition continously and as soon as that condition is met the program should execute. Can this be done. I thought of using crontab where script runs every 5 min or so but now I want that to be done without crontab

Comment: If it's not a script that runs continueously, you should use cron.
Here is the explanation of the condition I gave in the begining of my post :
If the first argument of the programm is not "--" then : Run the same script with argument "--" and the errors are redirected elsewhere (/dev/null is a trash folder) as well as standard output.
Then exit.

There you can do a while [ true ] to make it run indefinitely. In your while loop, just add a sleep function with the time you need (5minutes for you) and after that it's a regular bash script.    
Here is an example : http://pastebin.com/us76BRKj

Comment: In fact nohup do the same thing as the condition I gave you. But it's an independent program so your script will depend on it. With this solution, it will be a standalone program. So no, no need to use nohup with that.

Comment: Actually i have developed one script in unix that checks the directory space and if it exceeds certain limit it delets the file of that disk. Now I want that script run after continously or every 1hr.can you please help me how to use this with following script....#!/bin/sh
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
case 'df /tmp' in
*" "[5-9]?%" "*) rm -f /tmp/af.*;;
esac

Comment: Could you please paste it on pastebin ? So that I can help you ?
Because there are too many characters that disapears on stackoverflow if you don't put this in a code tag. PS : Why is there the declaration of your PATH value here ? This isn't supposed to be placed here, it must be declared in your .bashrc or .bash_profile

Comment: Did it work ? Or did you use screen or nohup ? ^^ Just to know if my solution fits with your problem =)

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned before, you need to use nohup to prevent the process from getting the hangup signal (hence no-h-up).

However, if you start the process in the background to begin with, as

```
prompt> nohup process &
```

that has the disadvantage of not allowing you to enter any data that may be required to get the process started off. This may be passwords/credentials or other input the process needs.

If you have that requirement, start it without the "&" at the end, enter your input and then hit Ctrl-Z to put the process to sleep. To send it to the background, type "bg" at the prompt and hit Enter.

```
prompt> nohup process
Enter password:
(Now press Ctrl-Z)
[1]+  Stopped                 process
prompt> bg
[1]+ process &
```

Now even if you log off, the process will continue to run in the background.

Alternatively if you are using bash or zsh, if you didn't start the process with nohup to begin with, and killing it and restarting is not an option then you can use the built-in disown command. First pause and background the process. And then stop hangup signals from reaching it.

```
prompt> process
Enter password:
(Now press Ctrl-Z)
[1]+  Stopped                 process
prompt> bg
[1]+ process &
prompt> disown -h
```

Note: If you've got other background jobs running, you need to provide the jobspec to only disown this specific job.

```
prompt> disown -h %1
```

Instead of [1] if you'd seen [2] when you paused and sent the process to the background, you'd say `disown -h %2` instead.

Comment: Thanks. I also added an explanation for preventing SIGHUP from being sent for processes not started with nohup in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

As well as starting it in the background, as above, you may need to use 'nohup'. This means it will carry on running, even if you close the terminal.

nohup ./abc.sh &

Answer (score -1):

start it in background using & operator e.g.

./abc.sh & this will continue till (a) the execution is complete or (b) you kill it or (c) system reboots

Comment: This isn't right, if you logout this will stop, you could use `nohup` to prevent this but I prefer screen.