# Linux Script - How To Keep It Running Even When Logged Out?

Tags: linux, background, nohup

I just started a CS GO server, I would use TCAdmin a GUI for making game servers but since Counter Strike GO is in beta, doesnt work too well with it. My question is I have a script called ./srcds_run  then I run it. Works perfect. But how would I make it run as a background process so I can just log out and leave the server there?

Thanks,
    necro.

Comment: The answers to this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445201/how-can-i-continously-run-a-unix-script-in-background-without-using-crontab/10447884 - tell you how to do the same thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work:

```
nohup  ./srcds_run &
```

This puts your command in the background and has it continue to run after you log out [[nohup man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup)]

Answer (score 2):

The `screen` utility will enable you to run a process in 'detached' mode:

```
screen -d -m ./srcds_run
```

[screen man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen)

Answer (score 0):

You could start your script from the rc.local file, if you want it running from boot up.

If you want it running only manually, I like the nohup idea.